# javascript getJson or html page that contains json xdk

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have a page that send me a json. You can send the request by GET method:

http://htmldiprova.altervista.org/android_login_api/getAccountXdk.php?unique_id=56d7fa82eddce6.56824464

or POST METHOD:

http://htmldiprova.altervista.org/android_login_api/getaccount.php
argument --> unique_id=56d7fa82eddce6.56824464

Now I try to download this information inside my mobile application developed by Intel XDK but I can't read this content with javascript jquery etc etc.
Anyone help me?

Comment: please post your code..

Comment: and btw the "page" is not returning a json it's returning an html that looks like json...

Comment: i found a error. I insert in my php page this line of code:
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `XMLHttpRequest()` object and use `JSON.parse()` on the responseText so the json string turns into an object.

```
    var myUniqId = "56d7fa82eddce6.56824464";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', "http://htmldiprova.altervista.org/android_login_api/getAccountXdk.php?unique_id="+myUniqId, true);

    request.onload = function() {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log(resp);
        alert(resp.resultAccount[0].box); // Meeting Sporting Club 
      }
    };
    request.send();
```

Check your console for the object paramaters. Also feel free to ask any questions as comment to this answer.

Also read about XHR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest